# What is it called when you like something, but then find a better version of that thing and no longer enjoy the original thing?

Tags: phrase-requests

For example, you really love SPAM *for some weird reason.* Then you decide to take a trip to Spain, where you fall in love with genuine Spanish ham. Then, once you come back home, you look at a can of SPAM and you're completely disgusted.

Comment: You can say jokingly, ["I've seen the light"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/see-the-light) or "I've been converted" or "once  you've had the real McCoy, [there's no going back](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/back)"

Comment: A common expression is exemplified by: '[Once you've touched an extraordinary cashmere](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1ASRM_enGB617GB618&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22Once+you+discover%22+%22ruined+for+anything+else%22), **you're ruined for anything else**.' This doesn't spell out that you've already had poorer versions, but probably strongly suggests it. It's often used in Christian circles to describe really meeting Jesus.

Comment: If you actually acquire the new in place of the old you can say you "traded up".

Answer (score 2):

You could say that ham *spoiled you for* SPAM. Here's [an example of the phrase from a novel by Jack London](https://books.google.com/books?id=4J7bDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT1592&lpg=PT1592&dq=%22spoiled%20him%20for%22&source=bl&ots=fNHLbJUygA&sig=qbMhGVN-QsKqh0TEdQm6acELv2A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjM6_Pt1ZrTAhVJ64MKHQX5Ab0Q6AEIMzAH#v=onepage&q=%22spoiled%20him%20for%22&f=false):

> Yet the beer seemed not as good as of yore. It didn't taste as it used to taste. Brissenden had **spoiled him for** steam beer, he concluded, and wondered if, after all, the books had **spoiled him for** companionship with these friends of his youth.

Answer (score 1):

"Jaded" is a word that comes to mind, as is the unpretentious "spoiled".

Example: "While on a brief visit to her hometown of Bushyhead, Oklahoma, Jennifer barely sampled the simple but hearty fare she used to love. Her tastes had become jaded during the years she was married to a Wall Street executive."

Answer (score 0):

*Dissatisfied* does suggest that you might have liked something before, so it may be what you're looking for:

> dis·sat·is·fied di(s)ˈsadəsˌfīd/ adjective adjective: dissatisfied
>
> ```
> not content or happy with something.
> "small investors dissatisfied with rates on certificates of deposit"
> synonyms: discontented, malcontent, unsatisfied, disappointed, disaffected, unhappy, displeased;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

That's sometimes referred to as having **fickle** taste.

M-W defines "fickle" as [marked by lack of steadfastness, constancy, or stability](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fickle).  You liked SPAM until something else came along.